# How to stop minimized Chrome windows opening automatically in Mac OS

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, dock

I often leave a Chrome window minimized in the Dock (with something I want to read/do later, and don't want to find again, for example). In the meantime, though, I'll often click on links in emails, etc., and these reopen the minimized window. Is there a way to stop this from happening (i.e. to stop things from activating the minimized window)?

Comment: Have you had any ideas since posting? I'm annoyed by the same thing.

Comment: I'm still having this issue in 2023. All 5+ minimized chrome windows popup randomly even without doing anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try and keep your current browsing in your main, initially opened window. Then when you are minimizing windows either break off the tab and minimize it or open a new window and copy and paste the URL.

You can experiment with this by opening a bunch of windows minimizing them and then clicking the Chrome icon in the dock to see which one opens.

Other options for saving for later are pinning tabs, or bookmarking a page with ⌘-D or ⌘-Shift-D which saves all open tabs as bookmarks in a new folder.

If you want to read more about how Chrome itself works, [here is a fun comic.](https://www.google.com/googlebooks/chrome/small_00.html)